# a disastrous slowdown of cudaMalloc in nvidia drivers from version 285

Tags: memory, cuda, driver, nvidia

recent years, we have used CUDA for time-critical tasks within many of our 64-bit projects. A few days ago I updated the nvidia drivers on my development system and found a disastrous slowdown of the algorithms associated with CUDA. After some digging, it became clear that many sequential calls of a cudaMalloc lead to a latency increase (with each next call):

```
void *p[65000];
for (int n = 0; 65000 > n; n++)
   cudaMalloc(&p[n], 256);
```

this code runs for about 4 seconds on nvidia drivers up to version 285 , but starting with the drivers version 285 execution of this code takes more than 8 minutes (120 times slower). tested on GeForce GTX 560Ti, GeForce GTX 460 and Quadro FX4600 on different x64 systems.

Well, the question is: is it a bug of the new drivers? or is it, maybe, some kind of attempt to deal with fragmentation and improving memory management in CUDA (through more complicated allocation)? or something else?

UPDATE:
I have reported this issue to nvidia and was answered that they were able to reproduce it and have assigned it for investigation.

Comment: I think it's due to smarter (more overhead) memory management.

Comment: @Anycorn good if so... but 120 times degrade... The road to hell is paved with good intentions? =))

Comment: Can you maybe allocate the memory as cont. bytes?  I tend to do that for small chunks.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a bug report to NVIDIA rather than a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: @Anycorn Yes, of course in some parts of my code I already have made appropriate changes. But our software is intended for working in 24/7 and often I just don't know the desired data sizes of target tasks. Of course custom memory management could solve the problem, but I haven't enough time and confidence for coding such fundamental and versatile engine =) Anyway, thanks for advice =)

Comment: @talonmies Maybe it should, but I was confused that there are several stable among beta releases with this issue. Anyway always there is a chance that you miss something obvious. So I prefered to ask here at first and if nobody here knows "the Truth", then I'll write a bug report =)

Comment: Please file a bug report and provide a code that reproduces the problem and our QA team will investigate.

Comment: @harrism yesterday I reported a bug to nvidia customer care (ref.num:120426-000060), but they redirected me to the developer section. after registration/approvement/etc, I was able to report the bug again just a few minutes ago. it's number is 125366

Comment: Make sure to factor out the long initialization time that happens at context creation time on CUDA 4.0.  This is caused by the driver's performing huge virtual allocations on the CPU, for UVA.

Comment: Actually that's a good point, but it wouldn't account for 8 minutes of allocation time.  That startup overhead is only a few seconds, and can be eliminated on linux by using nvidia-smi in persistent mode.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware harrism is right. to eliminate in my tests init latency in first call i tried cudaFree(0) at the begining. anyway, problem here is opposite to init latency at first call - the latency at first iterations is normal and minimal, but with each next call it grows more and more =(

Comment: @listar Do you know if the bug has yet been fixed? The current version we are running here shows the same behavior you are describing, and I'd like to know if this can be overcome by upgrading to a more recent version of Cuda/Drivers...

Comment: @user1428839 To be honest, we had no chance to try new version... because we couldn't wait for bugfix at that time and just redesigned our code to prevent unwanted behaviour. it was not very nice, but it works and one of the unwritten cybernetics laws says "if it works - doesn't touch" =))
Anyway, I'm pretty sure, that bug was fixed - I have got some positive email from CUDA-team about this issue and new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tracked this down based on the OP's bug report.  Turns out it was a known issue already reported and it is fixed in CUDA 5.0.  If you download the CUDA 5.0 <del>preview (available to registered CUDA developers)</del> Release Candidate or later you should see an improvement.

**edit**: The fix will be in the CUDA 5 RC, not in the preview.  So as of this edit (May 31, 2012), the fix is not yet available.